# Joomla template - is on homepage

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I want to create a joomla 3.x template which shows a different UI on the homepage than on all the oder pages.

This works fine with the following code:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$isHomePage = $menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault($lang->getTag());
```

When I click on a menu item $isHomePage is "false" and I can show a different layout.

But when I open an article from the featured articles-list on my home-page, the menu item is still the home page but the user does see the article.

How do I get the information, if the user is really on the home page?

Comment: When you have Joomla-based questions in the future, please search and engage the knowledgeable and dedicated community at Joomla Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, the home page condition getting true on inside page is due to the fact that if an article does not have any menu it gets it from the current menu. So clicking on home page article link carries home page menu id.

There are some alternative that I can suggest -

1) Checking for URL - Check if current URL is equal to site page URL.

```
$uri = JUri::getInstance(); 
$currentUrl = trim($uri->toString(),'/');
$homeUrl = trim(JUri::root(),'/');
$isHomePage = $currentUrl == $homeUrl;
```

2) Check for homepage parameter with inner pages parameters. For example, if your homepage is of the article and having id X, check from request params check `option` and `id` param to `com_content` and `id == X`.

I hope this might be helpful.

Comment: Tha'ts exactly the problem. The url idea did not work out of the box, but with some more logic I could get that somehow working. Thanks.